# Is it possible to reuse godog scenarios?

Tags: go, cucumber, integration-testing

I have a defined scenario in godog:

```
User starts a workspace with stack
    Given Minishift has state "Running"
    When user triggers workspace creation for stack
    Then workspace should be starting
    When user looks at the workspace status
    Then the workspace status should be running and creation successful
```

and I was wondering if it was possible to reuse this scenario for multiple stacks? Ideally, I would reuse this scenario for every stack and if that stack failed then I would fail that scenario but not all the tests. Each stack is independent of the others. I'm not sure if this is possible or if I have to manually define each stack as a scenario and do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

`Scenario Outline` with `Examples` (as documented [here](http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/guides/1.gherkin.html#scenario-outlines) for behat, but also implemented in Godog) does what you describe:

```
Scenario Outline: User starts a workspace with stack
    Given "<stack>" has state "Running"
    When user triggers workspace creation for stack
    Then workspace should be starting
    When user looks at the workspace status
    Then the workspace status should be running and creation successful
Examples:
    | stack     |
    | Minishift |
    | Redshift  |
    | Lateshift |
```

Your scenario will be called three times, with the parameters [`Minishift`, `Running`]; [`Redshift`, `Running`] and finally [`Lateshift`, `Running`] being passed to the first step.

Answer (score 0):

All of your steps in this scenario can be summarized as `Given minishift is "running" at workspace named "stack"`. The point is that this step definition can invoke all of your steps defined in the scenario described. And that is an usual practice in order to prevent redundant context in multiple scenarios.

The point in general is that, you can combine stack of steps into a single precondition and that is an usual composition of steps, which is an advocated practice.

Further more, I've noticed you have **two When** steps in your scenario definition and it is not something I would suggest. **When** is a single action and in order to prevent ambiguity, you should not have two actions in scenario, it cannot be clear, what exactly your scenario is about or why it fails exactly if it would. It just means in this case that you have two scenarios here instead of one.

Make your scenarios clear and small, it should be resusable and composable.

Another option is to **@tag** your scenarios needing minishift running for example:

`@minishift
Scenario: expected behavior
  When I do that action
  Then I expect this outcome`

Then you can use godog before scenario hook in order to start the minishift as expected.